# Will I get notifications from answers when I upvote a question?

Tags: support, notifications, up-votes

I know this is probably a silly question, but I couldn't find it Googling neither by searching this site.

I'm wondering if, to receive notifications from new answers, it is enough to upvote a question, or so I have to mark is as favorite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to star it in order to be notified. Upvoting a question simply means you think it was a well-written, well-researched and/or interesting question. Favoriting it, on the other hand, means *you* are interested in the question and you wish to keep track of its activity.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that but I upvoted some questions and never got notifications from them, but I couldn't find them back to see if I should've been notified :)